# ResearchKit: Validate email

Tags: ios, regex, swift, email, researchkit

I'm attempting to create a form step where one of the form step items is an email input. For this I want to validate the email against certain domains i.e.

> @gmail.com, @icloud.com, @me.com

I can see we have an email answer format in the form of this:

```
ORKEmailAnswerFormat()
```

However I can't see anywhere in this type that allows me to apply a validation regex. Looking into this I see we have the following

```
ORKAnswerFormat.textAnswerFormatWithValidationRegex(validationRegex, invalidMessage)
```

I suppose this is my best option? If so, would anyone know of a regex (my regex isn't the greatest!) in swift that would handle the 3 domains stated above?

I have something like this...(not the greatest i know!)

> [A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@gmail.com

Comment: [A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@(gmail|icloud|me)\.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@(?:icloud|me|gmail)\.com
```

(or, if you don't care about capturing:)

```
[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@(icloud|me|gmail)\.com
```

Now I made two modifications. I escaped the `.` and I made it so that the other two domains are options.

I suggest that you convert the whole thing to lower case. I don't know Swift, but you may be able to use one of its functions or the `i` modifier:

```
(?i)[0-9a-z._%+-]+@(icloud|me|gmail)\.com
```

Comment: Cheers buddy will leave it little longer to see if I can get a Research Kit answer - if not the ticks yours!